# Underscore: Array of objects to flat object. What's the magic?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am transforming this array of objects:

```
[
  {
    first: {
      blah: 1,
      baz: 2
    }
  },
  {
    second: {
      foo: 1,
      bar: 2
    }
  }
]
```

To this simpler, flat object:

```
{
  first: {
    blah: 1,
    baz: 2
  },
  second: {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2
  }
}
```

The two simplest ways I found to do this using Underscore/LoDash are:

```
// Using reduce and extend
_.reduce(myArray, _.extend)

// Using assign and apply
_.assign.apply(_, myArray);
```

The complete code is documented in a JSBin: http://jsbin.com/kovuhu/1/edit?js,console

I've read a lot of documentation on apply/bind/call/assign/reduce/extend… But I just can't get my head around what is actually happening behind the curtains.

Can someone help me understand the secret of the magic tricks both of these one-liners perform?

Comment: They perform dark magic, as they *mutate* the first of your objects. It should have been `_.reduce(myArray, _.extend, {})` (which desugars nicely to `extend(extend({}, myArray[0]), myArray[1])`)

Answer (score 4):

To understand this, let's make a simple version of assign (alias extend). We will only accept one argument, which we will call source, and we will add it to our result.

```
function assign(result, source) {

  var keys = Object.keys(source),
    length = keys.length;

  for (var i=0 ; i < length; i ++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    result[key] = source[key];
  }

  return result;
}
```

Now let's break the input into pieces:

```
var a = {
  first: {
    blah: 1,
    baz: 2
  }
}

var b = {
  second: {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2
  }
}

var input = [a, b];
```

Now we can call reduce:

```
_.reduce(input, assign);
```

reduce will call assign twice:

```
assign(result, a);
// assigns the (key, value) pair ("first", {blah: 1, baz: 2}) to result

assign(result, b);
// assigns the (key, value) pair ("second", {foo: 1, bar: 2}) to result
```

Talk is cheap, show me the code:
http://jsbin.com/hexiza/3/edit?js,console

You can see how assign is implemented using createAssigner() and baseAssign() in the [Lo-Dash source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/dist/lodash.js).

Comment: Thanks Andrew for showing yet another way of doing the same thing (reduce + assign). The example is very clear.

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` takes all values in an array/properties in an object, and [aggregates them](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L135). In this case `extend` is passed to `reduce`, meaning you're passing a  `function(a,b)` for extending value `a` (carried over with each step) with all the properties of object `b` (each value in your array, one at a time). In your one liner, underscore's `reduce` walks over your array, starting with an object {}, and simply dumps all the array element properties into that object as it walks along your input array. In plain JS it would be something like:

```
var thing = {};
var deeparray = [{...}, {...}, {...}];
deeparray.forEach(function(v) {
  Object.keys(v).forEach(function(k) {
    thing[k] = v[k];
  }
}); 
return thing;
```

`assign` ([not found in underscore](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L7697)) does the same thing, taking an array of objects and squashing them all together. That's literally the only thing it does. The call `_assign.apply(_, myArray)` is the same as _ calling `this.assign(myArray)` - `apply` is a base JavaScript function for calling a function while "manually overriding" what the keyword `this` means inside that function. `_.assign.apply(_,myArray)` is the same as calling `_.assing(myArray)` except with the added guarantee that `this` will be lodash, and not some random function scoped context.

Comment: Thanks, I now get what's happening with `reduce` and `extend`. Not sure I fully understand why _.assign(myArray) would not work and we need to override the `this` with `_`. Can you expand on that?

Comment: the function is internally bound from a different scope, so if you don't use `apply`, "this" refers to the top level function scope, from what I can see in the source.